# Why is this usage of dot operator illegal

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
    int a;
    int* p=&a;
};
int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.*p=10;
    cout<<obj.a;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused. Why is the line "obj.*p=10" illegal?
I think that *p can replace a, which means that obj.*p is equivalent to obj.a.

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where are all the `#include`s ?

Comment: `A` has a member named `p`. You can use `*(obj.p)=10` or even `*obj.p=10`.
But `A` has no member named "`*p`", that would be an illegal name.

Comment: Sorry. I just want to make the code as short as possible.

Comment: The type of `&a` is `int*` not `int (A::*)`. You can confirm this using a simple `static_assert`

Comment: To qrsngky:  but if I declare a member of an array int a[5] in the class, I can use obj.a[0] to access that element. Is a[0] a member? And I can't write obj.*a to access a[0]. But I think a[0] equals to *a.

Comment: @qrsngky — the first sentence in your comment is correct. The second one overlooks the `.*` operator, which is used with a pointer-to-member. `p` is an ordinary pointer, not a pointer-to-member, which is why the compiler complains.

Comment: @蔡天意 The synatx `.*` is reserved for pointer to member syntax. And since `p` is not a pointer to member but an ordinary `int*`, we cannot use that syntax here.

Comment: `a[0]` is not a member, but `obj.a[0]` is `(obj.a)[0]`, not `obj.(a[0])`.

Comment: @user12002570: thanks. so,  .* is a reserved operator. it can be use only when the pointer is a pointer to member.

Comment: @蔡天意 Yes exactly.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree that it does not answer the question of "why this usage is illegal". But then for that `obj.*p` to work, it needs `int A::* p = &A::a;` to be accessible from the scope of the `main` function, so there is indeed no member `*p` in the context of OP's code

Comment: @qrsngky -- I might not have been clear. The C++ grammar mostly uses maximum munch, so in `obj.*p` the two punctuation characters are the single token `.*`. There's no `*p` in that expression. Unlike `obj.  *p`. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker I see. The OP thought `*p` was a member of `obj` that could be accessed using `obj.`, but that's not the case, as it is actually tokenized as `obj` followed by `.*` followed by `p`, there is no separate `.` or `*` token

Comment: The compiler tries to find a `p` in the scope. But then it doesn't exist in the scope (not even an ordinary `int*`) so the compiler should complain. Indeed that's the complaint in some compilers, `error: 'p' was not declared in this scope`, not "type mismatch", for example [this one](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/)

Answer (score 1):

**tldr;**

`p` is an ordinary pointer and not an pointer to member. That is, `p` is `int*` but not `int (A::*)`. So `.*` cannot be used like the way you're using it with an ordinary pointer.

---

`.*` and `->*` are actually [pointer to member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators) while the type of the member `p` is an `int*` and not `int (A::*)`. This means that you cannot use pointer to member syntax here but instead should use normal syntax that we use to dereference an ordinary pointer.

```
*(obj.p)=10; //access member named p and then dereference the resulting pointer
```

You can confirm this by adding an `static_assert`:

```
class A{
    public:
    int a;
    int* p=&a;
    void f()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&a), int*>); //passes
        // static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&a), int (A::*)>); //fails
        
    }
};
```

Comment: If the type of member `p` is changed to `int (A::*)` instead, is there a syntax that makes the program work?

Comment: @qrsngky If `p` was `int (A::*)` then the simple `(obj.*p) = 4;` would work. See [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s4Kh5f8ee) I created to show this.

Comment: In that demo, `p` is not declared as a member of the `class A`, but rather as a local variable in the `main` function

Comment: @qrsngky It is trivial to modify the demo I gave to make `p` a member once one understands the concept. I modified the above demo where `p` is now a member. See [modified demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c8TnvhWr3). Then the syntax would be `(obj.*(obj.p)) = 4;`

Comment: Ok, so the syntax becomes more complex and in that case it's no longer just `obj.*p`. So basically, one way or another, the OP needs to change the structure of the code.

Comment: @qrsngky Yes, but the point I am making is that `.*` is/should be seen as a single operator(aka pointer to member operator) and then the code is modified accordingly.